# けど/が at the end of sentence but doesn't indicate contradiction?

Tags: grammar

> 先生から授業がないと聞いたんだけど...

There is no implication of contradiction yet けど is used. Please explain?

Comment: See Also: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32826/5010 and http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24754/5010 and http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19155/5010 and so on... Search "sentence end けど" and you'll get lots of related questions. Basically it's just "a context setter".

Comment: There is no contradiction? I think there is. 
先生から授業がないと聞いたんだけど...
I heard from the teacher that there will be no class (but it seems there will be).
The end of the sentence was omitted but it seems to me to imply a contradiction.

Comment: ^ When someone says 先生から授業**が**ないと聞いたんだけど..., it's unlikely that it implies "I heard from the teacher that there will be no class (but it seems there will be)" 「先生から授業**が**ないと聞いたんだけど... (授業はありそうだ)」←?? Rather, it can continue like 先生から授業がないと聞いたんだけど...(どうしてかな？/ 帰っていいのかな？/ 補講はいつだろう？ etc) I heard from the teacher we have no class today (so why is that? / so can we go home now? / and when will we have a make-up class? etc...)